# Regex breaks with "/" character instead of newline

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk

I tried making a RegEx for Splunk search that should extract the TLD from URLs. The source is Panorama Logs.

RegEx: `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?<host>[^\/]+)?(?<tld>\.[^.?\/\n]+).*$`

Test data:

```
https://example.org/
qq.com
https://border.example.com/?bridge=basket&blood=animal
360.cn
http://example.com/?brother=bike
smugmug.com
shop-pro.jp
```

The RegEx and testdata is on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ezGAml/4); I generated the test-data using randomlists.com to anonymize source data. The capture-group <tld> is needed; <host> is only there for readability.

> Describe what you tried,

Matching the TLDs from a set of URLs; some with a preceding protocol, some without. Input records should be separated by newlines, and matches should never be longer than one record.

> what you expected to happen,

All TLDs are matched and in the capture-group <tld>.

> and what actually resulted.

Lines ending with a `/` work, but lines without don't.

Comment: I don't have access to Splunk, but your regex is ambiguous. Try to restrict exactly what can or cannot be matched. In particular, the trailing `.*$` will eat as much as possible if you let it. Maybe try something like `^(https?://)?(?<host>[^/]+)(?<tld>\.[^.?/]+)(?:[?/].*)?$`

Comment: @tripleee I tried replacing it `[^\n]` so it should match all remaining, non-newline characters but it still only broke off at the slashes.

@CasimiretHippolyte yours seems to work, and is much simpler (seems like i was overthinking everything, as i always do). Thank you a lot for the working regex. I would like to mark it as answer but i don't know how

Comment: These are comments, not answers. Maybe wait for @CasimiretHippolyte to post a proper answer; if they don't, feel free to post an answer of your own, and marking it as accepted in a couple of days. Convention is to mark an answer as "Community wiki" if you didn't come up with it yourself; this forfeits any reputation points for upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the TLD you can use:

```
/^[^.\n]*[^\/\n]*\.\K[^\/\n]+/gm
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/T7sCsY/1)

*(If you search a single line, `\n`s aren't needed, you can remove them all form the character classes)*

**Explanation:**

Since it doesn't exclude the slash, the first character class with a greedy quantifier "jumps" over the slashes of the eventual scheme part and stop at the first dot.
The second character class that excludes the slash, stops at the first slash of the path part and then the backtracking comes to the game until it reach the last dot of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex), this can all be done with [`eval`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) and [`mvexpand`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/mvexpand)

A run-anywhere example:

```
| makeresults
| eval urls="https://www.example.org/|http://example.com/|ca.gov|http://blade.example.com/bikes/airplane.php|http://alarm.example.com/|smugmug.com|shop-pro.jp|https://example.org/|qq.com|pcworld.com|symantec.com|360.cn|http://example.com/?brother=bike|http://www.example.com/behavior/bead.php|army.mil|https://example.com/boy/bedroom.php|https://example.com/|https://www.example.com/brother?activity=believe|https://www.example.net/achiever/bottle.html|http://believe.example.com/bit?bait=base&bone=ball|aboutads.info|http://www.example.com/|http://www.example.edu/afternoon|livejournal.com|http://border.example.com/box/afterthought|oaic.gov.au|https://www.example.edu/base.php|house.gov|smh.com.au|http://www.example.edu/|https://www.example.org/|lycos.com|https://border.example.com/?bridge=basket&blood=animal|hibu.com|http://example.com/"
| eval urls=split(urls,"|")
| mvexpand urls
| eval busted=split(urls,":")
| eval busted=mvindex(trim(split(trim(replace(mvfilter(match(busted,"\.")),"\/"," "))," ")),0)
```

I combined the last several steps into one line, but this is what it's doing:

- break the URL list based on the pipe ("`|`") character
- `mvexpand` the multivalue field
- `split` each individual URL on the `:` character (if it's not there, there's nothing to `split`
- select the 0th (first) element of the following `match`ed `split` in an `mvfilter`:

  - everything that has a period ("`.`") that
  - has slashes ("`/`") replace with a space (" ") and
  - is split on the space (" ")

Your desired fqdn is now in `busted`

Extracting the TLD is now trivial. Append the following:

```
| rex field=busted "(?<tld>[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+?\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)$"
```

Or, to keep with just an `eval`, skipping `rex` entirely, do this:

```
| eval tld=mvindex(split(busted,"."),-2) +"."+ mvindex(split(busted,"."),-1)
```